# Terraform Code for MIG does not open port

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have Terraform code for an instance that is like so

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "main-app" {
  name         = "main-app"
  machine_type = "e2-medium"
  zone         = "us-west2-a"
  metadata = {
    "gce-container-declaration" = <<-EOT
            spec:
              containers:
              - name: app
                image: default/app:v2
                stdin: false
                tty: false
                ports:
                  - containerPort: 8080
                    hostPort: 8080
                  - containerPort: 2022
                    hostPort: 2022
              restartPolicy: Always
            # This container declaration format is not public API and may change without notice. Please
            # use gcloud command-line tool or Google Cloud Console to run Containers on Google Compute Engine.
        EOT
  }
  tags = [
    "https-server", "http-server"
  ]

  ...blah blah
}
```

And when I SSH into and listen to the ports I can see they are exposed

```
minh@main-app-1234 ~ $ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
systemd-r  323 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv4   1795      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
systemd-r  323 systemd-resolve   16u  IPv4   1797      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.54:53 (LISTEN)
container  391            root   10u  IPv4  14526      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:43673 (LISTEN)
sshd       566            root    3u  IPv4  15138      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       566            root    4u  IPv6  15139      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
app        945         chronos    7u  IPv6  16950      0t0  TCP *:8080 (LISTEN)
app        945         chronos    8u  IPv6  17496      0t0  TCP *:2022 (LISTEN)
```

However when I make it a template and in an instance group like so

```
resource "google_compute_instance_group_manager" "main-app" {
  zone = "us-west2-a"
  name = "main-group"

  named_port {
    name = "tcp"
    port = 443
  }

  named_port {
    name = "http"
    port = 80
  }

  version {
    instance_template = google_compute_instance_template.main-app.id
    name              = "app"
  }
  base_instance_name = "app"
  target_size        = 1

}
```

When I SSH into it and listen to the ports, it is not exposed

```
minh@main-app-1234 ~ $ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
systemd-r 324 systemd-resolve   14u  IPv4  14373      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
systemd-r 324 systemd-resolve   16u  IPv4  14375      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.54:53 (LISTEN)
container 389            root   10u  IPv4    986      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:46335 (LISTEN)
sshd      447            root    3u  IPv4  14741      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd      447            root    4u  IPv6  14742      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
```